# порядковый номер 387 не найден в библиотеке dll ssleay32.dll

Tags: php, denwer

Обновил php на Денвере на версию "PHP 5.6 VC11 x86 Thread Safe (2016-Oct-14 20:34:04)".
И теперь после запуска Денвера выдает ошибку "порядковый номер 387 не найден в библиотеке dll ssleay32.dll".
В чем может быть проблема, и как его решить?

Спасибо.

Comment: не знаю что это за библиотека, но для php 5.6 нужен апач 2.4.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский поставил апач 2.4. Ошибка исчезла, но теперь сайты не открываются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, если кому нибудь понадобиться.
Нашел готовый Денвер с обновленными PHP и Apache на этом сайте:   http://drupalbook.ru/drupal/denwer-obnovlenie-php

Там еще, есть инструкция по обновлению.